# PHP file_get_contents() problem

Tags: php

I tried to sent an SMS using an API with file_get_contents() in PHP.

Eg.

```
file_get_contents("http://testsmssite/SMS.php?username=xx&password=ccc&message=MESSAGE&numbers=1111111111&sender=11111");
```

In local machine it works well.

If i Put it in to server[SERVER A] its not working.If i change the code
ie.
`file_get_contents("http://google.com");` it works fine in both server and local.

if i put this page ie

```
file_get_contents("http://testsmssite/SMS.php?username=xx&password=ccc&message=MESSAGE&numbers=1111111111&sender=11111");
```

in to another server[SERVER B] it works fine.

If it is any problem with my [SERVER A] then how it open google?

Can any one help me to fix this issue ?

Comment: not sure, but perhaps your hosting server is configured to prevent requests to certain group of sites.

Comment: http get request...  so exposing usernames and passwords isn't an issue?

Comment: Are you getting any errors when on Server A?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `file_get_contents`, try using [`curl`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php). See what you get back as a response and check [`curl_error`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php). There are many possible reasons that could cause the request to fail.

Answer (score 2):

Check your error log. If `file_get_contents` fails, it tells you the reason why in the PHP error log if you log warnings and notices.

In a related question, [Why doesn't file_get_contents work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724467/why-doesnt-file-get-contents-work), some have created [a collaborative wiki answer that deals with how to trouble-shoot `file_get_contents` in detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724467/why-doesnt-file-get-contents-work/6724479#6724479). Maybe the infos and comments help you as well.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if `allow_url_fopen` is true/enabled, for more http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen? It could be a reason. And yes, Curl could be a better option.

Answer (score 0):

Check if http://testsmssite is accessible from Server A (try pinging it). Maybe you'll have to add it to /etc/hosts. Or maybe you have to change settings on testsmssite. IMO it's network issue, not related to PHP itself (since on server A PHP is able to load data from http://google.com)