# file_get_contents failed to open stream when reading content from YouTube

Tags: php

i try to read contents from any URL with PHP. Here is my code (localhost):

$f = file_get_contents('http://www.youtube.com');

but i get this message:

> failed to open stream: A conection attempt failed because the
>   connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or
>   establised connection failed because connected host has failed to
>   respond.

when i open http://www.youtube.com/ directly it's fine. So there isn't wrong with my connection.
Is this failure depend on my php configuration or something else?

Comment: working for me also...

Comment: did you start php before your code???

Comment: Jonathon Reinhart: meanwhile the deleted answer about youtube protection was correct. Google quickly bans people who steal their data with dummy scripts.

Comment: oh it is. When i use internet connection in my campus which using proxy it happens. otherwise is success. so my question now is how to run the script in my campus?

Comment: @Andre Aditya Pratama: you cannot - google don't like thefts.

Answer (score 1):

I just want to suggest `cURL`. `cURL` is best method to parse websites than `file_get_contents`.

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init("http://www.example.com/");
$fp = fopen("example_homepage.txt", "w");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

http://www.sitepoint.com/using-curl-for-remote-requests/

cURL doesn’t require any configuration.
some webhosts block the function files_get_contents so cURL is best every time.

Why file_get_contents is not working for this You can read SO ans.

[Why doesn't file_get_contents work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724467/why-doesnt-file-get-contents-work)

Comment: Why do you think your code should return different results?

Comment: I am not saying that my code should return diff result. i am just giving another option and suggesting if file get content is not working.

Comment: "and suggesting if file get content is not working" --- well, from my experience people suggest something different if it supposed to work differently. So the question is: why do you think your code is different from the OP's one?

Comment: the example_homepage.txt is empty for me

Answer (score 0):

here it is:

```
<?php
    echo file_get_contents('http://www.youtube.com');
?>
```

It is working perfect in both chrome and firefox, i don't what's wrong with you?
check it again....

Comment: This is not an answer

Comment: this is what i tried on my side, i have shown the code with complete php tags, which could be the problem with the user who is not getting the result, as it is working fine for me....