# RSS-Feed returns an empty string

Tags: php, rss

I have a news portal that displays RSS Feeds Items. Approximately 50 sources are read and it works very well.

Only with a source I always get an empty string. The RSS Validator of W3C can read the RSS feed. Even my program Vienna receives data.

What can I do?

Here is my simple code:

```
$link = 'http://blog.bosch-si.com/feed/';

$response = file_get_contents($link);

if($response !== false) {
    var_dump($response);
} else {
    echo 'Error ';
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [how to debug file_get_contents()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724467/why-doesnt-file-get-contents-work)

Comment: Are there any errors in your log? Make sure error logging is enabled.

Comment: u have to use User-Agent , that /feed/ script checks for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The server serving that feed expects a User Agent to be set. You apparently don't have a [User Agent set in your php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.user-agent), nor do you set it in the call to `file_get_contents`.

You can either set the User Agent for this particular request through a [stream context](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php):

```
echo file_get_contents(
    'http://blog.bosch-si.com/feed/',
    FALSE,
    stream_context_create(
        array(
            'http' => array(
                'user_agent' => 'php'            
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Or globally for any http calls:

```
ini_set('user_agent', 'php');
echo file_get_contents($link);
```

Both will give you the desired result.

Comment: more effective :) perfect answer

Answer (score 2):

blog http://blog.bosch-si.com/feed/ required some header to fetch content from the website, better use curl for the same.

See below solution:

```
<?php
$link = 'http://blog.bosch-si.com/feed/';
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Host: blog.bosch-si.com', 'User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.80 Safari/537.36'));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if( ! $result)
{
    echo curl_error($ch);

}
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
```