# WebScraper showing blank page, no output? PHP

Tags: php, domdocument

So I am trying to make/remake a Web Scraper in PHP using DOMDocument. The project I have to complete needs to be in native PHP, so no using cURL. I looked at using reg expressions but DOMDocument seems better.

Anyways I cannot get it to output and I am not sure why. Am I not calling something forward right?

```
<?php
class WebScraper{
private $url = 'http://todaysinfo.net/top-15-most-dangerous-airports/?utm_source=outbrain_airports&utm_campaign=outbrain_airports';
private $elements = array('title', 'p', 'img');
private $scraper_doc = null;

public function __construct($url){
    if($url){
        $this->url = $url;
        $this->scrapeData();
            if($this->scraper_doc){
                $this->parseData();
                $this->outPut();
        } else {
            echo '<p style="color: red;">Something happened with DOMDocument."';
        }
    }
}
function scrapeData(){
    $urlContents = @file_get_contents($this->$url);
    if($urlContents){
        $this->scraper_doc = new DOMDocument();
        libxml_use_internal_errors(TRUE);
        $this->scraper_doc->loadHTML($urlContents);
    } else {
        echo '<p style="color: red;">Didn\'t grab all of the contents."';
    }
}
function parseData(){   
    foreach($this->$elements as $element){
        $scraper_row = $this->scraper_doc->getElementsByTagName($element);
        foreach($scraper_row as $row){
            if($element == 'img'){
                echo $row->getAttribute('src') . "<br />";
            } else { 
                echo $row->nodeValue . "<br />";
            }
        }
    }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: stop using `@` to suppress errors. it's the (childish) programming equivalent of stuffing your fingers in your ears and going "lalalalala can't hear you".

Comment: `@file_get_contents($this->$url);`  -> `file_get_contents( $this->url );`.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
$urlContents = @file_get_contents($this->$url);
                                         ^
```

You're not accessing the `$url` you specified in the object definition. You're accessing `$this->null`, because `$url` is undefined in the scope of the `scrapeData()` method.

```
php > $x = new StdClass();
php > $x->foo = 'foo';
php > var_dump($x->foo);
string(3) "foo"
php > var_dump($x->$foo);
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: foo in php shell code on line 1
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot access empty property in php shell code on line 1
```

Comment: After fixing this, I still get no output.

Comment: I also had     foreach($this->$elements as $element){ and fixed it to $this->elements, still no output

Answer (score 0):

I think it will help if you change this line:

```
$urlContents = @file_get_contents($this->$url);
```

To this line:

```
$urlContents = @file_get_contents($this->url);
```

And change this line:

```
foreach($this->$elements as $element){
```

To this line:

```
foreach($this->elements as $element){
```

Then if I run your code like this for example, I get a result:

```
$webScraper = new WebScraper(null);
$webScraper->scrapeData();
$webScraper->parseData();
```

You can also check if `file_get_contents` is working. If it does not, maybe [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724467/why-doesnt-file-get-contents-work) can be helpfull to you.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I made those changes as above and am still not getting any output. I have another program I wrote that is much more simple that uses file_get_contents...I know the function is working on my computer. I do not see where it could be being called incorrectly in this code but am open to suggestions.