# Deserialize JSON response (PHP)

Tags: php, json, json-deserialization

I wanted to print the name of the coin (obtained from a JSON response of a site) + "test" when the page is loaded; the problem is that only "test" is printed as if it did not find the name of the coin.

PHP code:

```
<?php
     $coinbase = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker";
     $array = array("/bitcoin","/ethereum");

     find();

     function find(){
         $coin = file_get_contents($GLOBALS["coinbase"].$array[1]);
         $coin = json_decode($coin, TRUE);
         $v = $coin['name']."test";
         echo $v;
     }
?>
```

JSON structure:

```
[
   {
      id: "bitcoin-cash",
      name: "Bitcoin Cash",
      symbol: "BCH",
      rank: "4",
      price_usd: "1042.72",
      price_btc: "0.114721",
      24h_volume_usd: "462221000.0",
      market_cap_usd: "17742232718.0",
      available_supply: "17015338.0",
      total_supply: "17015338.0",
      max_supply: "21000000.0",
      percent_change_1h: "1.59",
      percent_change_24h: "-4.49",
      percent_change_7d: "-14.31",
      last_updated: "1520950752"
   }
]
```

Comment: Your payload is of an array type. To retrieve, for example, the first element, you would need something like $coin[0]['name'].

Comment: `$array` is not accessible in `function find()`. Read about [variable scope in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) then forget everything about `$GLOBALS` or `global`.

Comment: I have already tried to do $coin [0] ['name'] but it does not work

Comment: I also request you to read about variable scope in PHP as @axiac commented previously

Answer (score 1):

If I try like this I got the answer. I've printed the `$coin` for your clear understanding How can you easily access 2D array with its index `0` here.

```
  function find()
  {
    $coinbase = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker";
    $array = array("/bitcoin","/ethereum");
    $coin = file_get_contents($coinbase.$array[1]);
    $coin = json_decode($coin, TRUE);
    //printing only for debug purpose 
    print '<pre>';
    print_r($coin);
    print '<pre>';
    $v = $coin[0]['name']."test";
    echo $v;
  }

  find();
```

**Output:**

Printing it just for your clear understanding why I used `$coin[0]['name']` index to get the name from 2D `$coin` array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => ethereum
            [name] => Ethereum
            [symbol] => ETH
            [rank] => 2
            [price_usd] => 687.193
            [price_btc] => 0.0760364
            [24h_volume_usd] => 1696390000.0
            [market_cap_usd] => 67457446384.0
            [available_supply] => 98163757.0
            [total_supply] => 98163757.0
            [max_supply] => 
            [percent_change_1h] => -0.63
            [percent_change_24h] => -2.36
            [percent_change_7d] => -16.98
            [last_updated] => 1520955853
        )

)
```

**This is what you want**

```
Ethereumtest
```

**N.B**: Please note here the comment of https://stackoverflow.com/users/4265352/axiac carefully

> $array is not accessible in function find(). Read about variable scope
>   in PHP then forget everything about $GLOBALS or global

**As per comment:**

```
$coinbase = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker";
$array = array("/bitcoin","/ethereum");
function find(){
    global $coinbase;
    global $array;
    $coin = file_get_contents($coinbase.$array[1]);
    $coin = json_decode($coin, TRUE);
    print '<pre>';
    print_r($coin);
    $v = $coin[0]['name']."test";
    echo $v;
}
find();
```

Comment: Tested and it doesn't work. 
I don't know what to do.

Comment: Did you run my code snippet? @MONS7ER I am getting the desired result then you are not getting it? may be `file_get_content()` not able to get data for you.

Comment: @MONS7ER clearly see on my snippet I've made `$coinbase` and `$array` variable local. In your case *$array & $coinbase is not accessible in function find()*, so check it carefully

Comment: @MONS7ER I see you snap , you missed to declear variable `$coinbase` and `$array` before using it..that's why I told you to see my code snippet carefully. I just made the global variable local for easier use but you totally remove it :(

Comment: I can also not run it in a function and leave it completely global etc. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @MONS7ER OK :) I've updated my answer again. plz have a look.On my first answer I just make it `local` for the sake of simplicity. Now I make it like your old `global` scope code format. Also urge you to read http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php     Let me know not it working or not?

Comment: It does not work and I did copy paste; there will be a problem with hosting or something. At this point I do not know what to do but to thank you for the time spent. I will reread the page you have linked to me for the third time.

Comment: see this link https://eval.in/971229 here also the response is blank because `WARNING file_get_contents() has been disabled for security reasons on line number 7` that why it is only showing `test`

Comment: So the problem is not in the code but in the site that gives me the json?

Comment: No the site gives json perfectly. it is your code that is not able to get json from the site. If `file_get_contents()` doesn't work , you can try with `curl`. See this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/6724479/3723368

Comment: Set `error_reporting(~0); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` on your script

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$coin = file_get_contents($GLOBALS["coinbase"].$array[1]);
$coin = json_decode($coin, TRUE);
$v = $coin[0]['name']."test";
echo $v;
```

This json is an array of ojects so you should access first the index of the array and then, the property of the object.

**EDIT**

```
$coin = file_get_contents("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ethereum");
```

Try to hardcode the url to test it.

Comment: Is the `$coin` variable empty? If not, can you paste `var_dump($coin)` before trying the json_decode and after that?

Comment: before bool(false)  after NULL

Comment: This is the problem. file_get_contents() returns false if can't find the resource, so try modifying the url.

Comment: The url is correct, coinbase = "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker" array [1] = "/ethereum" and the site is correct https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/ethereum

Comment: @being-sunny is right, the probably error is that you are trying to access to `$array` inside the function.